# Conditional distribution of sum of iid bernoulli variables

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, bernoulli-distribution

How do I find the distribution of the following iid variables?

$X_i\sim Ber(p)$ , $n>m$

$$ P(\sum_{i=1}^m X_i | \sum_{i=1}^n X_i ) = \frac {P(\sum_{i=1}^m X_i , \sum_{i=1}^n X_i )}{P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i )}$$

Comment: It might be clearer if you wrote $P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^m X_i =a \mid \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i=b \right)$. This is not equal to  $\dfrac{P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^m X_i =a\right)}{ P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i=b \right)}$, and obviously not if $a > b$

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

- In effect, you will have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ ones out of $n$ with the rest zeros, and you want to know how many of these ones are in the first $m$
- The conditional probability will not depend on $p$ and will end up being a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)
- If you do not take that shortcut, you could investigate $\dfrac{P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^m X_i =a\right)P\left(\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^n X_i =b-a\right)}{ P\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i=b \right)}$